# How does FlexBright control screen blue light levels without using private APIs?

Tags: ios

I just read an [article](http://www.macrumors.com/2016/03/07/flexbright-adjust-display-temperature/) on MacRumors about a new app that allows the user to reduce blue light levels (like flux for Mac). The app has been approved and the same article states that the app achieves the control without using private APIs... So how *do* they do it?

Comment: No way they are doing it with a public API, but I'm not giving them money to find out for sure...